# How to add simple light effects to image using OpenCV or PIL?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I am working on a data augmentation module. I have already implemented some global augmentation techniques (related to contrast, brightness, color balance, etc) and now I want to move on to some local augmentations: add some local overlight or shadows to the image.

I tried choosing random rois (got unnatural sharp edges even after blurring) or creating random masks (lead to the same result as adding random noise).

How to do it using OpenCV or PIL lib so that the result would look natural?

Here are some examples (lights only, but I need shadows as well):

https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-flarefx.html

https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-lighting.html

https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-gflare.html

https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-nova.html

Comment: Gimp is Open Source, You can devote some time in learning their coding structure and then you can explore all these plug-in source codes.

Comment: Thank you, @ZdaR, that's what I am doing right now. I just wonder if there is an easier way. I thought that OpenCV or PIL might have some built-in tools that I fail to find.

Comment: Pil(low) and especially OpenCV are not build for artistic tasks, so i would not be surprised to not see those functions within those libs.

Comment: @sascha, thanks for the response. I know that, but I thought that a similar "artistic" effect might be possible to achieve using a combination of "non-artistic" functions.